# Get minimal days in first week use Java.Calendar

Tags: java, android, kotlin, calendar

Java `Calendar` a very strange thing that works in a very confusing way.
I try to make gaps of the first week of month. But `minimalDaysInFirstWeek` returns 1.
I have read the documentation and it seems that this is a normal situation. But stumbling across answers to similar questions, people using this feature got a different result.

[image]

```kotlin
fun weeksList(calendar: Calendar, month: Int): MutableList<String>{
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month)
    val firstWeek = calendar.minimalDaysInFirstWeek
    val weeks = mutableListOf<String>()

    for (day in 1..38) {
        if (day <= firstWeek)
            weeks.add(" ")
        else
            weeks.add("${day-firstWeek}")
        if (day == (calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + firstWeek))
            break
    }
    
    return weeks
}
```

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? What do you mean by *make gaps of the first week of month*? How do those gaps look? or better: how are they expected to look?

Comment: @deHaar i edit my Q. Check picture. Thank you

Comment: `Calendar` is a *very old* class, long replaced by classes of the `java.time` package. The documentation of `getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek()` states "*... the minimal days required in the first week of the year ...*" - not really related to the problem you want to solve - as I understand, you are basically interested in knowing the day of week of the 1st of a month (e.g. Monday -> no gap; Tuesday -> 1 day gap; Wednesday -> 2 days gap; ...)

Comment: @user16320675 I think what you said is more correct

Comment: Yes, the `Calendar` class is confusing indeed, or perhaps *was* confusing because we shouldn’t use it anymore. I too strongly recommend that you switch to `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). You may also look at `DayOfWeek` and/or `WeekFields` from the same API.